# variable depending on 2 variables conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability

Previosuly I have asked how to compute some conditional probabilities, but I am missing this particular case:

lets say we now have 3 variables:
$T$, $L$, $E$:

```
  T     L
   \   /
     E
```

So 
$E$ depends on $T$ and $E$ depends on $L$

I have these probabilities:

$P(T) =$ 0.0104
$P(L) =$ 0.055
$P(E) =$ 0.0648

$P(E|L,T) =$ 1.0
$P(E|L,\lnot T) =$ 1.0
$P(E|\lnot L,T) =$ 1.0
$P(E|\lnot L,\lnot T) =$ 0.0

How is modified the probability of $T$ and $L$ when we observe that $P(E)$ = 1?

Comment: It appears that problems of this type were addressed in your previous question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/bayes-network-computing-conditional-probabilities

Comment: Did you want to write P(E|L,¬T)= 1.0 instead of the second P(E|L,T)= 1.0?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a contradiction. Among ($T \land L \land E$, $T \land L \land \lnot E$, $T \land \lnot L \land E$, $T \land \lnot L \land \lnot E$, $\lnot T \land L \land E$, $\lnot T \land L \land \lnot E$, $\lnot T \land \lnot L \land E$, $\lnot T \land \lnot L \land \lnot E$) the $\lnot T \land \lnot L \land \lnot E$ is the only $\lnot E$ case that has a non zero probability. According to $Pr(E)= 0.0648$ this should have a probability of $1-0.0648=0.9452$. You also specified however that $Pr(T)=0.0104$ thus $Pr(\lnot T)=0.8996$. As the previously considered $\lnot T \land \lnot L \land \lnot E$ case is a member of the $\lnot T$ cases this should have a probability less then or equal to $Pr(\lnot T)=0.8996$. Alas $0.9452 \nleq 0.8996$, so your [$P(T) =$ 0.0104, $P(L) =$ 0.055, $P(E) =$ 0.0648, $P(E|L,T) =$ 1.0, $P(E|L,T) =$ 1.0, $P(E|\lnot L,T) =$ 1.0, $P(E|\lnot L,\lnot T) =$ 0.0] statements can not be simultaneously true.

I assume that your question is a formulation of a real problem to solve. So you have presumably not used the correct symbolic way to denote the problem. Maybe you could describe the problem in more detail in words?
Maybe you could separate which of your formulas correspond to facts, measurements that may be inaccurate or observations.

Comment: well, you are right, assuming there are not any numbers at all, how would the bayes formula look like? when I Observe $Pr(E)=1$, How $L$ and $T$ are modified? What probabilities are necessary?

Comment: As a first step calculate the ($T \land L \land E$, $T \land L \land \lnot E$, $T \land \lnot L \land E$, $T \land \lnot L \land \lnot E$, $\lnot T \land L \land E$, $\lnot T \land L \land \lnot E$, $\lnot T \land \lnot L \land E$, $\lnot T \land \lnot L \land \lnot E$) probabilities (I suggest using a spreadsheet), their sum must be 1. Then write zeros into the cells containing $? \land ? \land \lnot E$ as $Pr(\lnot E) = 0$. Then multiply each value with the same number to make the sum of the posterior probabilities 1.